# EF. Несколько связей между двумя таблицами

Tags: c#, entity-framework

Использую `CodeFirst`. Нужно сделать несколько связей между 2-мя таблицами.

Классы примерно такие:

```
public class User
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Topic> Topics { get; set; }

    public User()
    {
        Topics = new List<Topic>();
    }
}

public class Topic
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }

    public int TopicStarterId { get; set; }
    public User TopicStarterUserId { get; set; }
    public int? TopicModerId { get; set; }
    public User TopicModerUserId { get; set; }
}
```

**Вопрос 1:**
Как правильно именовать свойства в данном случае? Правильно ли именую `TopicStarterUserId`, `TopicModerUserId`? Подскажите, пожалуйста, правило именования для связывания один ко многим.

**Вопрос 2:**
Какие атрибуты / Fluent API нужно применять, если именование не соответствует правилам? Например, хочу обозвать `TopicModerId` просто `ModerId`.

**Вопрос 3:**
В данном примере получается что, чтобы сделать вторую связь (TopicModerId) нужно создать дополнительную таблицу `TopicModer` и связывать через нее? Если да, то как будет выглядеть данная таблица и связь через нее с `User` и `Topic`?

Comment: И ещё по правилам оформления вопросов на so: принято правилами хорошего тона задавать один вопрос - один топик.

Comment: @A K спасибо. Думал т.к. вопросы относятся к одной теме, можно задать все вместе. Скажите, сейчас лучше разделить и создать отдельные вопросы или оставить как есть?

Comment: Оставить, как есть. Действительно, весьма близкие по одной теме вопросы.

Comment: Поясните логику простановки модератора топика (вопрос 3), не совсем понятно. У топика может не быть модератора, может быть промодерирован кем-то. Если неоднократно модерировалось -- нужно сохранять всю историю кем модерировался? Мне кажется, тут сложно угадать, что конкретно вы хотите реализовать.

Comment: Модератор может либо быть, либо нет, всегда один, история не нужна. Исходя из вашего ответа ниже понял, что дополнительная таблица модераторов не понадобится, т.к. достаточно указать атрибуты, чтобы сделать 2 связи один ко многим.

Comment: Да, в такой формулировке достаточно двух связей один-ко-многим.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Расставьте нужные связи аттрибутами:

```
public class Topic
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Title { get; set; }

    public int AuthorID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AuthorID")]
    public virtual User Author { get; set; }

    public int? ModeratorID { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ModeratorID")]
    public virtual User Moderator { get; set; }
}
```

Названия свойств излишне начинать с Topic*

Вместо Starter лучше использовать термин Author.

```
public class User
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("AuthorID")]
    public virtual ICollection<Topic> TopicsAsAuthor { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ModeratorID")]
    public virtual ICollection<Topic> TopicsAsModerator { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: А если я захочу получить все топики одного пользователя, автором которых он является, вернет ли EF их при обращении к `user1.Topics` в рамках контекста? Как он узнает по какому ключу идентифицировать автора (AuthorID или ModeratorID)?

Comment: @Skrim дополнил ответ.

Comment: @A K большое спасибо, вопросов больше нет.